# angular2 - write input values in a .json file

Tags: json, angular, request, httprequest

building my application in angular2 i got some questions which don't seem to be answered in any tutorial:

i would like to store data from `input-fields` into a `.json` file which is local and part of my project (therefore in a directory - for example `../app/testdata/testdata.json`). By `GET` and `POST` i would like to receive or change the displayed data in the gui of my application.

is this even possible or is an external api/database for these requests required? 
is there a better way to do so if no backend is evaluated till now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a file is a server-side operation. You need a back-end. For example Node.js or ASP.NET.

Package for node.js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile